# Finding equation of position-time function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Dudley Do-Right is riding his horse at his top speed of $10m/s$ toward the bank, and is $100m$ away when the bank robber begins to accelerate away from the bank going in the same direction as Dudley Do-Right. The robber's distance, $d$, in metres away from the bank after $t$ seconds can be modelled by the equation $d=0.2t^2$. Write a model for the position of Dudley Do-Right as a function of time.

The answer is $d=10t-100$.

My question is how do you know that it is $-100$, and not $100$?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is $-100$ and not $+100$ because the positive axis was assumed to be along the direction of motion and Dudley's initial position was on the negative part of the axis where the origin is assumed to be the position of the bank.

Here's a depiction:

At time $t = 0$:

`-100m ............................ 0m ............................ +100m`
`Dudley ----->.................... Bank .................................`
`................................ Robber ----->..........................`

Answer (score 3):

*Draw a number line*, with the origin at the bank. Suppose the robber is moving to the right. Then her position at time $t$ is $(0.2)t^2$.

What about Dudley? The problem says that he is going *towards* the bank when the robber leaves, and that he is going in the same direction as the robber. So he must be to the *left* of the bank, at $-100$, when the robber leaves the bank. Thus he is at $-100+10t$ at time $t$.